# passing Json array to UIPickerView Not working

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray, uipickerview

i get data form JSON . Like this

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

   al=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"String String %@",al);

    for (array in al) {
        NSLog(@"array is  array %@",array);
    }
}
```

PickerView Methods:-

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
        return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
      numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
        return array.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return array[row];
}
```

I tried like this but it's showing empty PickerView.So Please give me any idea.

My Json like this:

```
[[1,"Hyd"],[2,"viz"]]
```

Comment: You are receiving 2D array, make sure you parse it like 2D array.

Comment: Try reloading the picker view after you get the data.

Comment: For your code to work you'd need your JSON to look like this: `["Hyd","viz"]`

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for replay i tried to reloading but not working [thePicker reloadAllComponents];

Comment: @SylvainGuillopé thanks for reply i need get json data to UIPickerView when i hit url on my browser it showing like this [[1,"Hyd"],[2,"viz"]] i tried but no luck so Please give me any idea

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
      return [((NSArray *)array[0]) count]; // check for boundary conditions
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
      numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
     return array.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return array[row][1]; // title exists at 1 index of each 2d array.
}
```

Comment: thanks for Replay as you said but still pickerview empty Please give me any idea

Comment: Make sure to connect `delegate` and `datasource`, either by IB or by code. This code works for me.